# Implementing a Generic Model with basic CRUD operation using ORMlite for Android

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have some abstract classes that I use as the base for all my models. For the sake of simplicity I will only talk about the root abstract class called model - which needs to handle some repetitive ORMLite operation. Before each crud operation, I needed to apply some logic standard to all models. So the point is that I can implement a save, update, and delete on the calling object, without having to repeat the code.

```
abstract public class Model<MODEL extends Model, CHILD extends ChildModel> {

    private final List<CHILD> mChildren = new ArrayList<>();
    private Class<CHILD> mChildClass;
    private Class<MODEL> mModelClass;
    protected RuntimeExceptionDao<MODEL, Long> mRTEDao;

    public Model(Class<MODEL> modelClass, Class<CHILD> childClass) {
        this.mChildClass = childClass;
        this.mModelClass = modelClass;
        this.mRTEDao = App.getOpenHelper().getRTEDao(this.mModelClass);
    }

    // some codes omitted...

    public void save() {
        // Do something to the object before continuing
        mRTEDao.create(this);
    }

    public void delete() {
        // Do something to the object before continuing
        mRTEDao.delete(this);
    }

    // some codes omitted...
}
```

The code above gives me an error because the DAO expects the sub class "MODEL" but instead **this** refers to **Model<MODEL, CHILD>**

The workaround to this at the moment is the below:

```
// some codes omitted...
abstract protected void handleUpdate(); // Let the subclass handle the create/update
abstract protected void handleDelete(); // Let the subclass handle the delete

public void save() {
    // Do something to the object before continuing
    handleUpdate();
}

public void delete() {
   // Do something to the object before continuing
    handleDelete();
}
// some codes omitted...
```

At the very least I reduce the code for each of the model - but it still doesn't seem elegant. Is there a way for me to grab the "this" object of the sub class and not the base Model class? I tried casting, but that gives me a warning that it is an unchecked cast.

```
public void save() {
    mRTEDao.create((MODEL)this);
}

public void delete() {
    mRTEDao.delete((MODEL)this);
}
```

This [project](https://github.com/Wackymax/CPOrm) for example has an elegant way for the model class to save, update, delete on itself. But unfortunately it lack features that I need in ORMlite, but I can't seem to get ORMlite to do the same thing in my project because of the need to generify the base Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh found a good solution for myself :) just simply implement an abstract method like this:

```
abstract protected MODEL getThis();
```

Here's the implementation:

```
@Override
protected ExampleModel getMe() {
    return this;
}
```

Then whenever I need **this** to behave like **this** of the subclass I'm using:

```
public void save() {
    // Do something to the object before continuing
    mRTEDao.create(getThis());
}

public void delete() {
    // Do something to the object before continuing
    mRTEDao.delete(getThis());
}
```